# Trying to send one list item through a search at a time

Tags: python, selenium

So I've got a text file of routing numbers that I need to check the validity of but I don't want to do manually. Right now, I've got a GUI that I'm inputting each one into (which is why that code is in there) but the plan is to turn the text file into a list and then have my program look up each one. I can't send all of them at once though, as I need to refresh the browser between each search (or clear the search bar). Using this code I've turned the text file into a list:

```py
with open('C:/users/ME/desktop/routingnumbers') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

How do I get my program to send each list item one at a time and then start over? This is my current program.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Routing Number Lookup")
window.configure(background="light grey")
window.geometry('300x250')

Routing = Label(window, text="Routing Number: ", font=("Arial"), fg="gray17")
Routing.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='e')
Routing.configure(background="light grey")
RoutingEntry = Entry(window, width=20)
RoutingEntry.configure(background="light grey")
RoutingEntry.grid(column=1, row=0)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.routingnumber.com/')

def RoutingSearch():

    SearchBar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]")

    RoutingInput = (RoutingEntry.get())
    SearchBar.send_keys(RoutingInput)
    SearchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ValidRouting = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]").text
    BankName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a").text
    print("\n")
    print(ValidRouting, BankName)

    driver.refresh()

SearchButton = Button(window, text="Search", command=RoutingSearch)
SearchButton.grid(column=1, row=3)
SearchButton.configure(background = "light grey")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to validate a routing number, use the following:

```
def validate_routing(rn):
  if len(rn) != 9:
    return False

  n = 0
  for i in range(0, len(rn), 3):
    n += int(rn[i]) * 3
    n += int(rn[i + 1]) * 7
    n += int(rn[i + 2])

  return n != 0 and n % 10 == 0

with open('routing.txt') as f:
    for rn in f:
      rn = rn.rstrip()
      print(rn, validate_routing(rn))
```

---

[Python Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/1ce6ce227e)

Comment: This works, but could you explain to me how? Big thanks either way.

Comment: Checksum algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number#Check_digit